# How to reduce internet speed

Tags: ios, macos, ipad

I have created an iPad app which deals with some API calls, it is working fine when there is internet available/unavailable. Now, I want to check app behavior with low internet speed. Is there any way to reduce internet connection speed? Currently I am on 4 MBPS, I want it to reduce to the dial-up speed.

Thanks,

Comment: Programatically? If not then not a programming question, I think...

Comment: programing or non-programing, anything...

Comment: If you are working in a company environment, the best option is to sit with your support/administration people (whoever doing firewall things) and ask them to reduce bandwidth to your (or your mobile device) ip..

Comment: @ACB - well that is good news, can you show me the way....

Comment: @AnkurS, Posted as an answer. It is possible in both device and simulator as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use network link conditioner as shown in this blog [USING NETWORK LINK CONDITIONER IN IOS 6](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/).

[image]

If you want to do this in simulator you can check this blog [New in OS X Lion: “Network Link Conditioner” utility lets you simulate internet and bandwidth conditions](http://9to5mac.com/2011/08/10/new-in-os-x-lion-network-link-conditioner-utility-lets-you-simulate-internet-and-bandwidth-conditions/)

[image]

You can install this by going to Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools and install "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode". You can double-click on the Network Link Conditioner.prefpane and it will install.

Comment: Thanks @ACB for this I was also curious how you could change the Network Condition's for the Simulator :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu, a software called Wondershaper, and a Wifi access point

Step:

1. Get a computer with 2 NIC
2. Install Ubuntu on a computer
3. Install Wondershaper software
4. Connect Wifi access point to NIC2. Connect Uplink (Modem/ADSL/Router) to NIC1
5. Configure speed you required by looking at link below [1]
6. Connect your Ipad to Wifi AP wirelessly.
7. Test

[1]http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/simple-traffic-shaping-ubuntu-linux/