# Strange crash when connected to "E"

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, networking

I have a strange internet connection issue. My app works fine when connected to 3G or WiFi, but I have a strange crash when connected with an "E" (see image below).

[image]

While on the "E" connection, the app will crash if I load a view that requires the Internet, then press the home button, then try to bring the app to the foreground. This only happens when on the "E" connection when bringing the app to the foreground.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here, and can't use the debugger because this only happens when the device is not plugged in.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: E is slower, so I can only assume you're loading something which is usually near-instant, and you're relying on that fact. Without a lot more details I can't help.

Comment: Try with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14210009/1730272 and try to figure out if it is happening in simulator or device when it is connected.

Comment: "can't use the debugger because this only happens when the device is not plugged in". Yes but you can log to the console and then read the console.

Comment: You're probably only going to E when your connection is total crap (as in the above screenshot, almost no bars). You're likely trying to make a connection that's failing (maybe partway through a download), and you don't have code to deal with the failure.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull crash logs off the device through Xcode's organiser window.

The E shows up when you are on an EDGE connection, which is quite slow.  You can replicate this type of connection by using the network link conditioner in Settings > Developer.